# Right way to call async function inside express js route

Tags: node.js, express

This is how I am doing now. but trying to see if there is a right or another way to do it.

```
async function getmanual_vars(req, res,ajax){
    var return_data = {};
    let db = await mongo_client.connect(mongo_url);

    let db_data = await db.collection('data').find({ created_by_user_id: req.cookies.user_id}).toArray();

    // more codes inside //

    res.json({ success: true});
}

router.post('/manual_vars', check_auth,function(req, res, next) {
    getmanual_vars(req, res,0);
});
```

Comment: You need a `try/catch` to handle the case where either of your promises rejects.  Also, it seems odd to even have the `ajax` parameter since you don't appear to use it.

Comment: Router.post('/manual_vars', check_auth, async (req, res, next) => { if(ajax) ..... }) but if you call async - dont forget about returns and try/catchs. And in javascript try not use underscores - use camal case notation instead

Comment: @jfriend00 its used, but I just didnt include in the sample. its in the more codes inside area

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
async function getmanual_vars(req, res) {
  try {
    var return_data = {};
    let db = await mongo_client.connect(mongo_url);

    let db_data = await db.collection('data').find({
      created_by_user_id: req.cookies.user_id
    }).toArray();

    // more codes inside //

    res.json({ success: true});
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ success: false, error: error });
  }
}

router.post('/manual_vars', check_auth, getmanual_vars);
```

This should have a catch for the possible errors and exceptions from your async function with status `500`.

As this is already a function that takes in `req` and `res`, we can just pass in the function itself to the router instead of having to create a wrapper around it.