# Invoking an async function from inside express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, callback, async-await

I have an async function in this form
`let test = async () => {}`
After this function, i have the `test.then().catch()` part.

I want this function to be invoked from inside router, by passing it the post parameters. Is this possible?

I came across this question:
[Right way to call async function inside express js route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48614785/right-way-to-call-async-function-inside-express-js-route)

But in that code snippet, he doesn't mention where the .tehn().catch() go to.
Also, can i pass parameters in my async function like it is right now (anonymous function).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure it's possible.  I'm not sure what you tried, but it's pretty straightforward:

```
router.post("/something", (req, res) => {
    // you can pass any arguments from the request here to your async function
    test(req.body).then(result => {
        res.send(result);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send("Error");
    })
});
```

> Also, can i pass parameters in my async function like it is right now (anonymous function).

Yes, you can.

```
let test = async (arg1) => {
    // since this is async, you would have some asynchronous operations in here
    console.log(arg1);
    return arg1;
};
```

---

FYI, that other question was using `await` so instead of `.catch()`, one would typically use `try/catch` with `await`.  Since you only asked about calling a single async function, you may as well use `.then()` and `.catch()` as `async/await` doesn't really make things shorter or simpler.

Comment: Your answer is great! But if the async function is not in the same file, i would just have to include the file it's in the beginning of my routes.js file? Is that correct?

Comment: @user1584421 - This is standard node.js, nothing to do with a route or with async.  If you want to call a function in another file, you have to "import" that other file with `require()` or `import` so you can get access to an exported function from that other file.